# How to dynamically define class variable as argument in function

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, function, class

I am not able to find correct title for my question because my problem is little bit wierd. Let me first explain my code

```
public class Route
{
   public String Id {get;set;}

   public string routeNo {get;set;}

   public string source {get;set;}
}
```

Class for data exchange. I have win form which have all the fields of route class. For each variable i have `label, TextBox, ErrorLabel`. I have function which will be called on leave.

```
 public partial class AddRoute : Form
    {
        Route r=null;
        public AddRoute()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            r = new Route();
        }

       private void textBoxSource_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
         showErrorLabel(labelSourceError, textBoxSource.Text, r.source);   
       }
    }
```

Object r of Route class in initialized in form constructor.

```
 private void showErrorLabelString(Label l, string textboxtext, Route.source a)
 {
     if ((string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)) || (s.Length > 50))
     {
         isError = isError && false;
         l.Text = "Please Enter Data and Should be smaller than 50 Character";
         l.Visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        a = textboxtext;
    }
}
```

Now its time to explain the problem. I want the common function `showErrorLabelString(Label l, string textboxtext, Route.source a`) for all textbox leave event which will check data is correct and if yes assign it to class variable. But problem is that what should be the `data type` in `showErrorLabelString()` to dynamically identify in which variable of class i need to assign value. Now you must think why you are doing like this, reason

- To improve performance
- All the data is validated at leave event and assigned in class object which will save few `if else condition` to check is data validated.
- To reduce load on button click event.
- And Finally is to try something different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need a [Action delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

It works like an function pointer that your function accepts as an argument, and when you call it, you pass it the function you want to execute.

```
private void textBoxSource_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    showErrorLabel(labelSourceError, textBoxSource.Text, val => r.source = val);
}

private void showErrorLabelString(Label l, string textboxtext, Action<string> update)
{
    if ((string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)) || (s.Length > 50))
    {
        isError = isError && false;
        l.Text = "Please Enter Data and Should be smaller than 50 Character";
        l.Visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        update(textboxtext);
    }
}
```

By this way, the showErrorLabelString remains completely independant from the type of the object you want to update.

Comment: in this my businessObject is r only.

Comment: Now you added some code, I slightly changed my example and renamed some vars.